# Counter is adding an extra digit

Tags: python, counter, digit

I'm making a game where a user rolls a dice, this works fine and then i calculate how many times each number has been rolled in my countVals function, however it counts incorrectly it counts 1 digit off.

if dice rolls
`5,1,3,1,5`

Expected result of counting would be
`2,0,1,0,2` as it counts how many times each digit has occured

Actual result currently is
`0,2,0,1,0,2`

Code is below

```
for x in range (6):
    #counter = dice.count(x)
    print(dice.count(x)
```

Comment: 1. Use `randint(1, 6)` if you want results in 1 through 6 inclusive; `randrange(1, 6)` gives results in 1 up to 6 (exclusive of 6). 2. Your `range(6)` makes `x` go from 0 through 5 inclusive - that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in range (6):
```

try this:

```
for x in range (1, 7):
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ranges are off (they need to be half-open intervals).

```
  randrange(1, 7)       # die roll is one of {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

The counting should likewise loop over:

```
  for x in range(1, 7):
      print(dice.count(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the range to:

```
random.randrange(1,7,1)
```

Remember parameters are:

```
randrange(start, end, step)
```

and it returns a value between [0, end-1] with a specific step.

Comment: Better to use `randint`, which includes both of the endpoints.